# ¿Cómo escribir REGEX que excluya una URL que contenga una palabra específica en la API de Google Analytics Reporting?

Tags: php, regex, google-analytics-reporting

Estoy escribiendo un código con la nueva API de [Google Analytics Reporting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4?hl=es). Quiero encontrar las páginas más visitadas en esta semana, **excluyendo** ciertas URLs, para el filtro uso REGEX y todo funciona bien, excepto con una expresión que no sé como ponerla.

Estes es el código donde creo el filtro:

```
$dimensionFilterExclude = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
$dimensionFilterExclude->setDimensionName('ga:pagePath');
$dimensionFilterExclude->setOperator('REGEXP');
$dimensionFilterExclude->setExpressions('^(evangelios|/biblia/comentarios/evangelios/|feature/comentarios-biblicos/|^/$|biblias.html|/liturgia-semana-+)');
$dimensionFilterExclude->setNot(true);
$dimensionFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause;
$dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilterExclude]);
$dimensionFilterClause->setOperator( 'and' );
```

Y la expresión que no está funcionando es la última, en `setExpressions`, o sea esta: **`|/liturgia-semana-+`**. Lo que quiero es que ignore URLs que tengan el término `/liturgia-semana-`, como esta por ejemplo:

```
/e92ac84894ac/liturgia-semana-xxxiv-del-tiempo-ordinario-ciclo-a
```

He intentado de varias maneras, usando también asterisco y otras cosas, pero nada funciona. Este valor es  aleatorio `e92ac84894ac`, y esto también cambia: `xxxiv-del-tiempo-ordinario-ciclo-a`, por lo que quiero ignorar todo lo que tenga `/liturgia-semana-`.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es necesario separar la búsqueda en dos grupos:

1. Los que deben aparecer al inicio de la cadena (o línea)
2. Los que pueden tener contenido anterior

Haciendo una prueba rápida:

```
$regExp = '/^(evangelios|\/biblia\/comentarios\/evangelios\/|feature\/comentarios-biblicos\/)|((.+)biblias.html|(.+)\/liturgia-semana-+)/m';
$urls = <<<URLS
evangelios/evangelio1.html
/biblia/comentarios/evangelios/otra-cosa
feature/comentarios-biblicos/mas-cadenas
/abassdadass/biblias.html
/e92ac84894ac/liturgia-semana-xxxiv-del-tiempo-ordinario-ciclo-a
/url-excluida/biblia/comentarios/evangelios/
/evangelios/excluida-por-diagonal-inicial/
/liturgia-semana-excluida/por-falta-elemento-inicial/
URLS;

preg_match_all($regExp, $urls, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Resultado:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'evangelios' (length=10)
      1 => string '/biblia/comentarios/evangelios/' (length=31)
      2 => string 'feature/comentarios-biblicos/' (length=29)
      3 => string '/abassdadass/biblias.html' (length=25)
      4 => string '/e92ac84894ac/liturgia-semana-' (length=30)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'evangelios' (length=10)
      1 => string '/biblia/comentarios/evangelios/' (length=31)
      2 => string 'feature/comentarios-biblicos/' (length=29)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '/abassdadass/biblias.html' (length=25)
      4 => string '/e92ac84894ac/liturgia-semana-' (length=30)
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '/abassdadass/' (length=13)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '/e92ac84894ac' (length=13)
```

Explicación:

```
/^(evangelios|\/biblia\/comentarios\/evangelios\/|feature\/comentarios-biblicos\/)|((.+)biblias.html|(.+)\/liturgia-semana-+)/m
```

- **^** Buscará al inicio de la cadena o línea cualquier coincidencia del primer grupo, esto ya lo tenías claro y funcionando:
  `(evangelios|\/biblia\/comentarios\/evangelios\/|feature\/comentarios-biblicos\/)`
- **|** Disyuntiva para buscar en el segundo grupo si no hubo coincidencias en el primero:
  `((.+)biblias.html|(.+)\/liturgia-semana-+)`
- **(.+)** Indica que puede haber cualquier caracter `.`, uno o más `+` antes de la cadena buscada, en este caso, `biblias.html` o `liturgia-semana-`
- **+** No sé porqué lo incluiste después de `liturgia-semana-`, no es necesario
- **m** El modificador multilínea es solo para probar

**Nota:** Estoy muy lejos de ser experto en expresiones regulares, pero tú ya tienes las bases y no podría haber sugerido algo sin [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Ha funcionado, era esto lo que buscaba: `/(.+)/liturgia-semana-+` En este contexto no pongo los caracteres de escape, supongo que la API se encarga de ello. Gracias genio, REGEX es un mundo casi desconocido para mi.